# how to apply match() to every buffers?

Tags: vim

I made a small function that highlight the current selection with a specified color by calling the matchadd() function. This is coupled with a map for easier use.

This works fine except it is execute only in the current buffer (or is it window ?)

I try to use the bufdo and windo just before the call in the mapping (see below) but I receive "Invalid address" error.

```
function! Mymatch(sel)
    "reselect and copy selection in unnamed reg
    normal gv""y 
    if a:sel == 1
        :call matchadd("MatchYellow",@")
    elseif a:sel == 2
        :call matchadd("MatchGreen",@")
    elseif a:sel == 3
        :call matchadd("MatchRed",@")
    elseif a:sel == 4
        :call matchadd("MatchBlue",@")
    elseif a:sel == 5
        :call matchadd("MatchPurple",@")
    elseif a:sel == 6
        :call matchadd("MatchWhite",@")
    elseif a:sel == 7
        :call matchadd("MatchOrange",@")
    elseif a:sel == 8
        :call matchadd("MatchPink",@")
    elseif a:sel == 9
        :call matchadd("MatchCyan",@")
    else
        :call matchadd("MatchYellow",@")
    endif
endfunction
map mm :call Mymatch(v:count)<CR>
```

where MatchYellow and so on are highlight groups I defined

what I would like to have, it the same behavior than * command. where all the matches are highlighted in every file I look into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The error

The *invalid address* error is caused by supplying a *count* in conjunction with the `:call` syntax. A mapping executes just like typed commands, so `9:` turns into `:.,.+8`, and your `call` is executed multiple times, once on each of those lines. If the range doesn't exist, you get this error. There's an easy fix: as you reference the count via `v:count` and need to be called just once, you don't need the range, and the `<C-u>` command (in command-line mode) clears the range:

```
map mm :<C-u>call Mymatch(v:count)<CR>
```

#### Applying everywhere

You're right, `matchadd()` only adds matches for the current window. If you have several windows, you need to use `:windo`. If you have additional tab pages, you need `:tabdo` as well. If you add additional windows and want the highlighting appear there as well (without having to re-execute your mapping), you need `:autocmd`s, e.g. on `WinNew`.

#### Additional critique

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- You don't need the `:` in front of commands inside a `:function`.
- To make your mapping work more like the built-in commands (e.g. `*`), it should use the *current word* (via `expand('<cword>')`) in normal mode, and only use the selected text in visual mode.
- Your conditional is cumbersome. You could instead put the highlight groups in a *List* and use the count to index into it:

```
call matchadd('Match' . ['None', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Red'][a:sel], @")
```

#### Plugin alternatives

It should be clear by now that it would take quite some work to turn your mapping into a robust solution. Fortunately, this idea isn't new and there exist several plugins to choose from. My [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) is one such solution. (The plugin page has links to many alternative plugins.)

Comment: thanks for this long answer ! I knew there was probably a plugin for that but I but I see it as a good small project to learn vim script and later be able to create more "personal" plugin. In any case, thanks for the link :)